# Which Java NIO SSL socket libraries to use in Android app?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, nio

There are different Java NIO SSL socket libraries like Netty, Jetty, Restlet etc, I want to get more like this, and evaluate them as the server to deliver messages like Firebase.